# Why is the password entered not comparing within my IF statement?(sharedpreference)

Tags: java, android, if-statement, sharedpreferences

I am doing my my assignment, and I am not sure why If statement not getting password stored in shredpreference and compare with the password entered in this page. I really want to know which variable(s) or particular part(s) I did wrong? please help guys!!!

```
package com.wheresmyphone;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Check_Activity extends Activity {

public static final String passwdfile = "passwd";

String passwd;
private static final String PREF_PASSWORD = "PassWord";
protected EditText PassWordField;
protected Button EnterButton;

SharedPreferences sharedpref;   
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_);

    final EditText userpassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    sharedpref = getSharedPreferences(passwdfile, 0);





    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String passwd = userpassword.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences passwdfile = getSharedPreferences("passwd",0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpref.edit();
            editor.putString(PREF_PASSWORD, passwd);
            editor.commit();
            //commit data
            String storedpassword = passwdfile.getString(passwd, null) ;  


            if (passwd.equals(storedpassword)) {

            startActivity(new Intent(Check_Activity.this, MainActivity.class));


                finish();




            }else {
                Toast.makeText(Check_Activity.this, "Incorrect Password, Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

        }



        });
}
```

Comment: Did you try logging the result from `storedpassword` and `password`?

Comment: U mean I should put if (password.equals(storedpassword)){......}   ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to retrieve the stored password with the wrong key. That is, change:

```
String storedpassword = passwdfile.getString(passwd, null);
```

To:

```
String storedpassword = passwdfile.getString(PREF_PASSWORD, null);
```

Comment: and, how can I reference the password from previous to the page above? please help !!

Comment: @user2893221: Sorry, I'm not completely following... previous what? `SharedPreferences` offer persistent storage, so you should be able to retrieve the stored password from anywhere within your app, provided you have access to a `Context` instance (e.g. `Activity`, `Service`, `Application` etc).

Comment: sorry about that, what I mean is I wanna reference password entered in previous page to the page above !! should I declare some variables or strings in order to achieve this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to transfer the password from one activity to another? If that's the case, supply the password as an extra piece of data to the `Intent` - [examples here](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html). If not, please clarify on what you consider to be the 'previous page' and 'page above'. Probably best to start a new question too, because it's a little out of scope with respect to the question you asked here.